# How to close specific pop-up window in asp.net using javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

Is it possible to close specific pop-up window when other page is clicked using javascript? Something like below...

```
function closePopUp()
{ 
window.close('popup.aspx');
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

if you open a pop with a name then it is possible

```
var popUp;
function OpenPopUp() {
    //popUp is the name of the window
    popUp = window.open("Yourpage", "something", "width=550,height=170");
  }
```

Then you can close it as follows

```
function closeit() {
    //closing a popup with name popUp
    popUp.close();
}
```

Comment: I call the closeit() function on button click of another page but it didn't work..

Answer (score 0):

```
OnClientClick="javascript:window.close()"
```

Comment: Your answer should contains an explanation of your code and a description how it solves the problem.